# ddply: how do I pass column names as parameters?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame where the column names are generated based on parameters - so I don't know their exact values. I want to pass these fields to ddply also as parameters.
I guess the answer is obvious, but can someone please turn the light on for me.

Example below using the iris data set that gives the idea of what I want to do, and the unintended result of my effort. The results of first example, iris1 is what I want to achieve, but by passing the column names in as parameters, as in my iris2 effort, that doesn't give me the intended results.

```
iris1 <- ddply(iris, .(Species), transform, pw_first = Petal.Width[1], 
              pw_last = Petal.Width[length(Petal.Width)])
myCol <- 'Petal.Width'
iris2 <- ddply(iris, .(Species), transform, pw_first = myCol[1], 
               pw_last = myCol[length(myCol)])

head(iris1)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species pw_first pw_last
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa      0.2     0.2
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa      0.2     0.2
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa      0.2     0.2
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa      0.2     0.2
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa      0.2     0.2
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa      0.2     0.2

head(iris2)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    pw_first     pw_last
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa Petal.Width Petal.Width
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa Petal.Width Petal.Width
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa Petal.Width Petal.Width
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa Petal.Width Petal.Width
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa Petal.Width Petal.Width
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa Petal.Width Petal.Width
```

Comment: Can you give a example of your "intended results"?  Is "field names" the same as "column names" aka variable names ?

Comment: The intended results are in head(iris1) - ie 0.2 in both columns. I want these values in head(iris2) but need to pass the column names as parameters. Yes fieldnames = columnnames.

Answer (score 2):

```
colName<-"Petal.Width"

iris1 <- ddply(iris, .(Species), function (x) {
               pw.first=x[1,colName]
               pw.last=x[length(x[,1]),colName]
               result=cbind(x,pw.first,pw.last)
               return(result)})

unique(iris1$pw.first)
[1] 0.2 1.4 2.5

unique(iris1$pw.last)
[1] 0.2 1.3 1.8
```

If you only want the species, and pw.first and pw.last, simple remove the x from cbind.

Comment: no, that's not it. your 1.8 in pw_last is not correct. That is the last record in the data set, not the last record in the group. The 0.2 and 0.2 in my example are actually correct. What I was struggling with was my iris2 example. How do I pass column names as parameters?

Comment: thanks - but your answer doesn't show me how to pass column names as parameters.

Comment: Edited my answer. I forgot that part, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. The idea in this solution is to use `get`, which looks for a variable inside the current environment. So `get(myCol)` will find `myCol` in the data frame being operated upon.

```
myCol <- 'Petal.Width'
iris2 <- ddply(iris, .(Species), transform, 
  pw_first = get(myCol)[1],
  pw_last = get(myCol)[length(get(myCol))]
)
```

Another approach, which might be simpler to understand

```
iris2 <- ddply(iris, .(Species), function(df){
  x = df[[myCol]]
  transform(df, pw_first = x[1], pw_last = x[length(x)])
})
```

Comment: In this case, you're better off not using `transform`

Comment: @hadley so you mean directly adding the columns to `df` and returning it inside the function? or are you suggesting use of `mutate`?

Comment: Yes, just modify the data frame directly.

Answer (score 0):

Still learning R, but I find the Function interface for ddply to fit my brain... Maybe this is close?

```
iris1 <- ddply(iris, 
               .(Species), 
               function(x,y) {result = data.frame(x$Petal.Width[1],
                                                  x$Petal.Width[length(x$Petal.Width)])
                              names(result) <- y
                              return(result)},
               c('first','last'))
iris1
```

Result:

```
     Species first last
1     setosa   0.2  0.2
2 versicolor   1.4  1.3
3  virginica   2.5  1.8
```

Or perhaps this?

```
iris1 <- ddply(iris, 
               .(Species), 
               function(x,y) {
                 result = cbind(x,x$Petal.Width[1],x$Petal.Width[length(x$Petal.Width)])
                 names(result) = c(names(x),y)
                 return(result)
                 },
               c('first','last'))
head(iris1)
```

result:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species first last
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   0.2  0.2
```

Ok, makes more sense now.  Passing an existing column of the data.frame as a parameter which then produces two added columns to the data.frame using the parameter column as the source of a calculation.  How about this:

```
iris1 <- ddply(iris, 
               .(Species), 
               function(x,y) {
                 len <- length(x[,1])
                 first <- x[1,y]
                 last <- x[len,y]
                 result <- cbind(x,first,last)
                 names(result) <- c(names(x),'first','last')
                 return(result)
               },
               'Petal.Width'
)
head(iris1)
```

Result:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species first last
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   0.2  0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   0.2  0.2
```

I hope you're going to do something other than 'first' and 'last' -- like a `mean` or `sd`  function.  first and last are dependent on the `ddply` function giving the anonymous function data in a known order ... I'm not sure if it does or not. You might get different, unexpected answers.

Comment: maybe getting closer - but I want to pass the column name 'Petal.Width' in as a parameter.

Comment: the last parameter to ddply `c('first','last')` names the columns attached by the function.

Comment: it is not the new column names I want to pass as parameters - it is the existing column names - ie 'Petal.Width'